# How to get total number of array elements for a particular field in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a sample json structure as follows:

```
[
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": [
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": [
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "b": [
      2,
      3,
      4
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 2
  }
]
```

I want to count the total number of elements in the collection for field `b`.

Currently, I am using a java code to literally traverse each document and counting the `b`'s array size and adding.

However, while I was going through MongoDB related articles (I am new to MongoDB), I found that MongoDB is rich in aggregations and filters. So I was thinking if it is possible to get the count of total number of array elements for field `b` in the collection using Mongo aggregations or filters without writing some Java code.

Comment: What should be the expected output? Do you want to find size of `b` field or sum all the elements inside the `b` field?

Comment: You can traverse the array serverside, e.g. with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation like this

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { $project: { count: { $size: "$b" } } }
])
```

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) are docs to `$size` operator.